# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se repita mi optgroup de un select?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, select2, options

Tengo un 'select' donde se muestran unos artículos con sus cuerpos legales. Necesito que el título de mis options no se repita. Actualmente se me muestra así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí adjunto el código en que armo el 'select':

```
 $.get('../api/v1/consulta/articulo', {}, function(returnedData) {

    if (returnedData["error"] == false) {
        console.log(returnedData["articulo"]);
        $.each(returnedData["articulo"], function(key, value) {
            var cuerpo_legal = value['cuerpo_legal']['descripcion'];
            var articulo = "Art.- " + value['numero_articulo'];
            console.log(articulo);
            $('#articulo').append(
                `<optgroup label="${cuerpo_legal}" id='cuerpo'>
                    <option value="${value['id']}">${articulo}</option>
                </optgroup>
                 `
            )
        });

    } else
        SweetAlert("error", "Existió un error. Por favor actualice la ventana.");
});
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que se muestre algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor explica mejor lo que quieres preguntar, lee [Ask] si no sabes como hacerlo, tu pregunta no es clara y podríamos acabar borrandola

Comment: Sería bueno que muestre que envía el servidor como respuesta al get que ejecuta